# Making multiple list items apply in python

Tags: python, list, artificial-intelligence

What I’d like to is make my code so that if I enter "You are a " plus a complement word (in the list) and or another word like "You are a nice robot" It will print out: "Thank You!"

Here is my code:

```
complements = ["nice","happy","good","smart","wonderful"]

def chat():
    input = raw_input("You: ")

        if input in "You are a ":
            if input in complements:
               print "TIM: Thank you"
        else:
            print "I don't understand"

chat();
```

No matter what I do, it automatically goes to the else statement

Comment: Please review the indentation; it's important in Python. But just think about what you're writing - if you enter *"You are a smart cookie"* what will the result of `if "You are a smart cookie" in "You are a ":` be?

Comment: Sorry, its just my code was a lot bigger than this and I made indentation mistakes while down sizeing

Comment: So could you please **edit the question** to provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) others can *actually try running*?

Comment: You know that's still not correctly indented, right?

Comment: It works on my computer

Comment: Yes, that is *now* correctly indented - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main problems:

1. `if input in "You are a ":` tests whether *the whole input* is in `"You are a "`, not whether that phrase is at the start of the input; and
2. `if input in complements` tests whether *the whole input* is in your list, not whether one item from your list is in the input.

Try something like:

```
def chat(compliments=["nice", "happy", "good", "smart", "wonderful"]):
    input = raw_input("YOU: ")
    if input.startswith("You are a "):
        if any(input[10:].startswith(c) for c in compliments):
            print "TIM: Thank you"
```

This gives me:

```
>>> chat()
YOU: You are a nice robot
TIM: Thank you
```

Comment: You could have `if any(complement in input for complement in complements):`

Comment: @Noelkd true, but that tests whether the word appears anywhere, not just following "You are a".

Comment: Fair this does exacally what the OP is requesting. Sad that you can't say `You are a really nice robot` :(

Comment: Thank you, but it still prints the else statement after it prints out the if statement

Comment: @Khanrad see edit to my answer - works perfectly here.